# How to extract h1 headings from an HTML page using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm still trying to get to grips with regexps and I'm considering a simple query. I'm trying parse the homepage of my website and extract the H1 tags.

```
  <?php
    $string_get = file_get_contents("http://davidelks.com/");
    
    
    $replace = "$1";
    
    $matches = preg_replace ("/<h1 class=\"title\"><a href=\"([A-Z]|[0-9]|[a-z]|[\s]|[\x21]|[\/]|[\-]|[\.]|[\£]|[\:])*\">([A-Z]|[0-9]|[a-z]|[\s]|[\x21]|[\/]|[\-]|[\.]|[\£]|[\:])*<\/a><\/h1>/", $replace, $string_get, 1);
    
    $string_construct = "Mum " . $matches .  " Dad";
    
    echo ($string_construct);
    
    ?>
```

However, instead of just displaying the first HTML link using the $1 token, it just pulls in the whole page. What can I try next?

Comment: Are you trying to learn regex, or just parse your website? If the latter, I suggest looking up a DOM parser such as PHP's SimpleXML.

Comment: @Cole: You should use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) for parsing websites. SimpleXML will only accept valid XML or XHTML. Truly valid XHTML is hard to find. A single mistake and nothing happens, unlike HTML parsing.

Comment: @netcoder oh right, that's the one I've used before. DomDocument. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like something that could be done easily with a [DOM parser](http://php.net/dom):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('http://davidelks.com/');
$h1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0);
echo $h1->textContent;
```

You should get:

```
Let's make things happen in and around Stoke-on-Trent
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if this is your site or a site you manage, but there shouldn't be more than a single `<h1>` tag in a HTML page (there is a couple on the homepage).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm a journo trying to learn a bit of code, and regex just seemed to be an ideal way of being able to create HTML by extracting and concatenating specific elements. I also appreciate the tip about the homepage. I'll take a look

Comment: Why shouldn't there be more than one `<h1>` tag in a page?

Comment: @CanSpice: Because `<h1>` should be the most relevant content in a page. By having multiple `<h1>` tags, you give different content pieces the same importance. While it is still unclear whether [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) allows it or not (there's a guideline regarding [Meaningful Sequence in 1.3.2](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-content-structure-separation-sequence) that seems to make sense), search engines usually use `<h1>` and `<title>` tags for determining the most important content. By repeating them, you risk having an incorrectly parsed page and lower rankings.

Comment: It looks as though it's part of the Drupal template I've got. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in your usage of `preg_replace`. You wanted to **extract** something, for which `preg_match` is to be used:

```
<?php
 $text = file_get_contents("http://davidelks.com/");

 preg_match('#<h1 class="title"><a href="([\w\s\x21\/\-\.\£\:]*)">([^<>]*)</a></h1>#', $text, $match);

 echo "Mum " . $match[1] .  " Dad";
?>
```

Note particularily that you can combine character classes. You don't need `[A-Z]|[a-z]|[..]` because you can just combine it into one `[A-Za-z...]` square bracket list.

Also try to use single quotes for the PHP string, if you want to search double quotes within. This saves a lot of extraneous escaping. As do alternative enclosures `#` instead of `/` around the regex.

Comment: Thank you. As I say, I'm learning but absolutely love the goodwill and support available

Comment: I s\ee \t\o\o m\uc\h un\nec\cess\ary e\s\c\ap\in\g \in t\he c\h\a\ra\ct\er cl\a\ss.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier using a DOM parser. But if you would want to do it with regex you should use the [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) function in php:

```
preg_match_all("/<h1 class=\"title\"><a href=\"([A-Z]|[0-9]|[a-z]|[\s]|[\x21]|[\/]|[\-]|[\.]|[\£]|[\:])*\">([A-Z]|[0-9]|[a-z]|[\s]|[\x21]|[\/]|[\-]|[\.]|[\£]|[\:])*<\/a><\/h1>/",$string_get,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```